# Make drive similar to windows in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: partitioning

I have recently installed ubuntu 16.04 . Followed steps from internet and created root(24 gb) , swap(2 gb) and /home (remaining space which is more than 450 gb) . As I come from windows background. I want drives in similar fashion i.e. under computer folder I want to create different drives with different sizes (similar to windows drive d , drive e , drive f) . Please help me .

Comment: Don't take your Windows ideas into Linux. It will be a BAD experience. We do things differently for a reason (mostly the answer will be: Linux is multi-user system). As a well-known person once said: Think Different!

Comment: Thanks  Rinzwid :) . I am just curious whether I can do it or not as new user it look different . I think it takes some time to adapt Linux file system.

Comment: It basically is a matter of getting used to. Think about how long you have been using Windows. That is why it is so easy to you. Same goes for Linux for me: I have been using it since 2006. It is bound to be easy for me ;-)

Comment: Note that Windows refers with *drive* to what Linux refers with *filesystem* (or *partition* on harddisks and SSD). *Drive* is a bad word as it may refer to the phyiscal device as a whole. So, in Linux you have mount points to mount the filesystems - which is conceptually quite different from what Windows does.

Comment: Why not learn how to use Linux properly rather than try and use it the way it's not meant to be?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Linux you can make partitions and mount those in directories. You can use 2 fixed locations and a personal named one.

```
/media/
/mnt/
/personal_directory/
```

- The 1st is used for
  removeable media such as floppy disks, cdroms, USB and zip disks.
- The 2nd is a generic mount point under which you mount your filesystems or devices.

There is no limitation to creating a mount-point anywhere on your system but by convention and for sheer practicality do not litter your file system with mount-points.

---

If you want to add partitions install and start up [gparted](http://gparted.org/) and **carefully** shrink the partitions you have now. This will get you "unallocated space". Divide that space up into the sizes you want and add a unique name to them (that is called a mountpoint).

We already have a good answer about partitioning here: [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Example: I have a HDD called "discworld" (created during installation):

[image]

Partition layout is stored in `/etc/fstab`:

```
$ more /etc/fstab
...
# /discworld was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=22653238-5821-4c7c-9baa-99e938a6a259 /discworld      ext4    defaults      
...
```

- `sudo blkid` will get your the UUID you need at the beginning of the line you need to add. [More about this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingUUID).
- The directory (here `discworld`) and filesystem (here `ext4`) is set when you finished creating them with gparted. We have a [wiki page about adding new partitions to fstab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab).

Comment: Thanks :) It is very helpful. Links helped me understand about file system in Linux.

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy.html is a must read ;-)

Comment: Note it should be `/media/$USER`

Comment: @cat not perse. /media/cdrom0 and /media/cdrom1 are valid too.